# When not to use docker run --init

Tags: docker

The [`--init` flag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#specify-an-init-process) of `docker run` causes the `tini` init system to be used as the `ENTRYPOINT`. As a consequence, the application running in the container will be a child process of the init system so that it can take care of signal handling, zombie reaping etc.

`docker-compose` also has an `init: true` service setting.

As [`tini` works transparently, Dockerfiles don't need to be modified in any way](https://github.com/krallin/tini) (that's what that `tini` docs say).

So my questions are:

- Are there any downsides to using `--init`?
- Under which circumstances would it be better to avoid using `--init`?
- In case there are no serious downsides: Why is `--init` not the default setting?

Answer (score 7):

There are no downsides of using the **--init** flag. However, tini the process that gets to be PID 1 in your container does not cover all functionalities of a init process.
For most cases, this shouldn't be a problem as you just want SIGNALS handling and child processes handling.

> Under which circumstances would it be better to avoid using --init?

If you coded your application to handle SIGNALS, for example in NodeJS:

```
const registerSignals = () => {
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
    console.log('SIGTERM received');
    shutDown(0);
});
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
    console.log('SIGTERM received');
    shutDown(0);
});
}
```

AND if you have no zombie processes to reap
OR your reaping zombie processes yourself

then you can avoid using **--init** or **tini**
(Make sure to use exec form when starting your container if you want the above snippet to work)

> In case there are no serious downsides: Why is --init not the default setting?

Because making your containers SIGNAL aware as my snippet shows is not so difficult and besides you might have some exotic case for PID 1 that tini does not cover so there is no good reason in injecting tini per default in all containers.

EDIT: Added Cameron's suggestion

Comment: 1.) Which are the init system functionalities that tini doesn't cover? I could not find a spec of what should be supported.
2.) tini forwards signals to its children, so signal-aware applications should work (this is not a reason to avoid tini).
3.) There are a LOT of standard images that don't run properly without --init. For example, MariaDB's entrypoint script mishandles SIGTERM; in the context of docker-compose, that leads to MariaDB getting killed after a while. This type of problem would not occur if tini was the default (maybe plus a --no-init flag for special cases).

Comment: When you run a container without -p or --net=host its basically useless. Nonetheless the default is to map no ports to the outside.  Basically what I am saying is that having docker do too much is not a good solution.    again I think in some cases you would want to have your own init process because tini is not something like systemd

Comment: It seems to me this answer should mention that if you are handling signals yourself, then you don't need Tini if you have no zombie processes to reap and/or your are doing your own zombie reaping. I think that should be explained.